# Google App Engine - iPhone messenger client

Tags: iphone, ios, google-app-engine, entity, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to make an app that will be deployed on both the App Store and Google Play. It involves sending data to a server, so I decided to try Google App Engine. I have looked at Google's Tic tac toe service, but I'm not sure it's what I want. Basically, what I want to do is to be able to send data to the server using a bundled `Entity`, and to be able to read it back. Does the `Endpoints` service fulfill this need, and if not, where would I find something that does?

Thanks.

Comment: Endpoints does, but I'd steer clear. I've tried it for two projects now, and both times been forced by bugs to rewrite in a different framework.

Comment: See this: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-hello-world-example/